# How to access DbContext in viewmodel with AspNetCore 2.1?

Tags: entity-framework-core, viewmodel, dbcontext, asp.net-core-2.1

Using DropDown input fields is very common when you want to display a description while saving an ID in your database.
If I consider my Person model, I have PersonViewModel which has a SelectList used to display a list of possible Job Descriptions

```
    public SelectList SelectJobDescription
    {
        get
        {
            MyDbContext _context = new MyDbContext();
            var result = new SelectList(_context.Keywords
                                    .Where(k => k.Name == ".JobDescription")
                                    .OrderBy(r => r.Valuename), "Valuecode", "Valuename");
            _context.Dispose();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

and I use this SelectList in my create/edit views like this:

```
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="JobDescription" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select asp-for="JobDescription" asp-items="@Model.SelectJobDescription" class="form-control">
                    <option>Select a Job Description</option>
                </select>
        </div>
```

Is it correct to use _context this way in the ViewModel or there is some other way to do the same thing better (maybe DI?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property after instatiating the view model (or during initialization), for example:

```
var vm = new YourViewModel()
{
    SelectJobDescription = new SelectList( _context... ),
};

return View( vm );
```

Comment: This thing works, so i'll accept your solution. Anyway, the final result is that all my  controllers will be polluted with code to initialize VM properties, defeating my attempt to encapsulate these activities in the "Initialize" method of my VM. I still do not understand the reason why I cannot use DbContext inside viewmodel

Comment: one of the primary roles of the controller methods is to gather and organize the data required by the views (I.e. view models).  You can pass the DbContext to the view model via constructor argument or parameter in a manually called initialize method for code reuse purposes though I’d recommend simply using a helper method in the controller class the initialize the view model(s) instead.